# Adobe ColdFusion 2016 testbox BDD elvis operator issue

Tags: coldfusion, bdd, coldfusion-2016

Update:  Submitted a bug report for this issue, [Bug #4150051](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4150051)

---

You could call ?: as elvis operator / ternary operator / null coelscing. It is very poor implementation & luck of proper documentation about this operator in ACF.  There are some issues while using it in TestBox (Tried both v2.3.0+00044 & 2.2.0+00021) BDD. Here I have created very simple test bundle (aTest.cfc) to demonstrate this issue.

```
component extends="testbox.system.BaseSpec"{
    function run(){
        describe( "checking the ACF issues in ternary operaors", function(){
            it( "Just dump, it will pass. But see the dump above", function(){
                itemTypeConfig = {};
                writeDump( itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null" );

                itemTypeConfig = {"someConfig":"abcd"};
                writeDump( itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null" );
            } );

            it( "Check with elvis operator inside expect", function(){
                itemTypeConfig = {};
                expect( itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null" ).toBe(1);

                itemTypeConfig = {"someConfig":"abcd"};
                expect( itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null" ).toBe(1);
            } );

            it( "Check with expect with some temp variable", function(){
                itemTypeConfig = {};
                var actualResult = itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null";
                expect( actualResult ).toBe(1);

                itemTypeConfig = {"someConfig":"abcd"};
                var actualResult = itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null";
                expect( actualResult ).toBe("abcd");
            } );    

            it( "Check with expect with struct key exists", function(){
                itemTypeConfig = {};
                if ( structkeyexists(itemTypeConfig, "someConfig") )
                    var actualResult = itemTypeConfig.someConfig;
                else
                    var actualResult = 1;
                expect( actualResult ).toBe(1);

                itemTypeConfig = {"someConfig":"abcd"};
                if ( structkeyexists(itemTypeConfig, "someConfig") )
                    var actualResult = itemTypeConfig.someConfig;
                else
                    var actualResult = 1;
                expect( actualResult ).toBe("abcd");

            } );    

        } );
    }
}
```

While running this test case in Lucee, there is no problem. But in Adobe ColdFusion, I am getting errors. refer attached the screen shot of the test result.
[image]
1. You can see dump are coming as undefined in first spec.

2. In second spec, if you give the elvis operator inside the expect, `expect( itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null" ).toBe(1);` It is giving actual undefined
3. In third spec, I am trying to use temporary variable as work around to fix the *actual undefined* issue in spec 2

   `itemTypeConfig = {};
   var actualResult = itemTypeConfig.someConfig ?: "I am null";
   expect( actualResult ).toBe(1);`

   But it is giving actualResult is undefined
4. In fourth spec, I am using the struckkeyexists with out using this ternary operator in BDD test suites & it is working fine.

I tried to create similar behaviour in standalone cfm file, But I could not able reproduce it. I am not sure, whether it is issue in testbox or May be ACF handling the elvis operator inside the closures. I am not sure about the exact terminology to describe this issue

Comment: What if you try adding `var` before  each `itemTypeConfig` definition. Like this: `var itemTypeConfig = {};`.

Comment: Even though var is not relevant to this context, I already tried that too. Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: Can you reduce this to a single line of code (or perhaps 3 or 4) that show the issue on their own?  I think this question just has a lot of code and explanation so it gets skimmed over because it will take a lot of time to dig in and understand it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a parsing bug in Adobe ColdFusion Release 2016. (It works in ColdFusion 11).  I reduced your example down to this code which demonstrates the issue.  It only happens when you have nested the closure call at least 2 deep.

```
clos = function( func ) { func(); };

clos( function(){
    clos( function(){
        writeDump( foo ?: "I am null" );
    } );
} );
```

The output is "**undefined**" as you reported, yet "**I am null**" is expected.

Please go to the [Adobe Bug base](https://bugbase.adobe.com/) and put in a ticket.  Until it is fixed, you won't be able to use the elvis operator in your BDD tests.

I would recommend simplifying your question to use this, much smaller repro case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your simplified example to mimic my issue & As you have mentioned this example & my test suite working fine in CF 11 but not in CF 2016, I will log a bug in Adobe bug base